# Pull right button with input in header

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to pull on the right in the header a button with a input text field, this is my code:

```
<div class="page-header">
    <div class="pull-left">
        <h2>Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
        <div class="form-group label-floating">
            <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput1">Search</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="focusedInput1" type="text">
        </div>
        <button id="show-hide-filter-button" class="btn btn-raised btn-default">Mostra Filtro</button>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

so as you can see, I have on the left the title of the header and on the right i want on the same line the input and one or more buttons, the problem is if I add only button it's work perfectly, all on the same line, if I add a form-group in input go in two line as you can see in the image below.

[image]

How can I have all in the same line?

Thanks

Comment: can you show the css of ".pull-left" and ".pull_right", ".form-group", ".label-floating" etc. etc.

Comment: Because the inputs in form group are in blocks
You should style ur classess within 'pull-right' to display inline elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make this div

> div class="form-group label-floating"

go inline with the button

> button id="show-hide-filter-button"

using css **"display: inline-block"** on the **div** (by default it goes with "display: block")

Answer (score 1):

Add display:inline to the .form-group, or display:flex to the .pull-right

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `Flexbox` just use `display: flex` on both header and `pull-right` class.

```css
.page-header, .pull-right {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-header">
  <div class="pull-left">
    <h2>Header</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="pull-right">
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
      <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput1">Search</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="focusedInput1" type="text">
    </div>
    <button id="show-hide-filter-button" class="btn btn-raised btn-default">Mostra Filtro</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The buttons and the field container should have **"display:inline-block;"**:

```
<div class="page-header">
        <div class="pull-left"  style="float:left;">
                <h2>Header</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right"  style="float:right;">
                <div class="form-group label-floating" style="display:inline-block;">
                        <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput1">Search</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="focusedInput1" type="text">
                </div>
                <button style="display:inline-block;" id="show-hide-filter-button" class="btn btn-raised btn-default">Mostra Filtro</button>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix" style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/m40mb9nj/)

```
<nav class="navbar page-header">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Header</a>
  </div>
  <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" placeholder="search" class="form-control search">
       </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-transparent">Mostra Filtro</button>
    </form>
   </div>
```